# GWT - How to determine which language to set and/or get client country/location?

Tags: java, servlets, gwt

I want to know what language to use when a client comes to my site but I can't find out to do that. Most of the solutions seem a little outdated e.g. [ClientLocation](https://gwt-google-apis.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/visualization/1.1/com/google/gwt/ajaxloader/client/ClientLocation.html).

What is the best approach to determine which language to use and how to do it with GWT?

I know I can get the client IP from the servlet but if I go that way I am not sure how to locate a user actually.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to discover the locale to use from the browser. You should follow the [documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nLocale.html#LocaleSpecifying), and use this property :

```
<set-configuration-property name="locale.searchorder" value="queryparam,cookie,meta,useragent"/>
```

You can see all the properties settable for i18n in [the module definition](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/master/user/src/com/google/gwt/i18n/I18N.gwt.xml). By default, GWT use this code to determine the useragent locale, and you can change it with a new property-provider, or use a server-side discovery :

```
var language = navigator.browserLanguage ? navigator.browserLanguage : navigator.language;
if (language) {
  var parts = language.split(/[-_]/);
  if (parts.length > 1) {
    parts[1] = parts[1].toUpperCase();
  }
  locale = parts.join(\"_\");
}
```

If you want to discover the country/location of a user, you can, from a servlet, use a GeoIP database. This kind of DB has a mapping from IP to country/states/city. It's generally easy to use and integrate into an application. See for example [Maxmind GeoIP Database](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/).

Comment: Is there a change that you can show me that in terms of Java code? I have set the configuration property in my client.gwt.xml and I am grabbing `LocalInfo.getCurrentLocale()` but I can't seem to get something like the country code or more important the language..

Comment: It does seem to work e.g. if I set the property-fallback but I can't find anything that gives me the language set by the browser :/